# How do I fix warped walls in my raycaster? (I have tried using cosine correction)

Tags: processing

I understand that there are a number of answered questions on here asking the exact same thing. However, I have tried to implement the solution (cosine correction) and have had little success. Note: it is not implemented in this version of the code.

In terms of my code, I'll upload the whole thing but the part that likely needs fixing is the Player class. The rest is fairly boring stuff. I also know that it runs based off of images that you won't have, but for testing feel free to use any 600x600 image that is only black and white. Or contact me for mine. White denotes walls. I'll also upload a screenshot of the warped walls. Controls are WASD for movement, plus some glitchy mouse controls to change the view (will be fixed) as well as hold m to see a map of the current level.
[Screenshot of it running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mX8Ph.png)

```
PImage maze;
int stepSize, renderDistance;
float viewStep, fov, moveSpeed;
float minLine, maxLine;
Player p;
boolean w, s, a, d, map;

void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
  background(0);
  strokeWeight(3);
  
  maze = loadImage("testmaze3.png");
  
  stepSize = 1;
  fov = PI/4;
  viewStep = fov/(width/4);
  renderDistance = 300;
  moveSpeed = 2;
  minLine = 0;
  maxLine = 200;
  
  colorMode(RGB, renderDistance);
  p = new Player(width/2, height/2, 0);
  
  w = false;
  s = false;
  a = false;
  d = false;
}

void draw() {
  maze.loadPixels();
  
  if (map) {
    pushStyle();
    
    background(maze);
    
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    noStroke();
    ellipse(p.x, p.y, 10,10);
    stroke(renderDistance);
    
    pushMatrix();
    translate(p.x, p.y);
    
    line(0, 0, renderDistance*cos(p.direction), renderDistance*sin(p.direction));
    
    popMatrix();
    popStyle();
  }
  
  pushMatrix();
  translate(p.x, p.y);
  
  if (w) {
    if (maze.get(int(p.x + moveSpeed*cos(p.direction)), int(p.y + moveSpeed*sin(p.direction))) != color(renderDistance)) {
      p.x += moveSpeed*cos(p.direction);
      p.y += moveSpeed*sin(p.direction);
    }
  }
  if (s) {
    if (maze.get(int(p.x - moveSpeed*cos(p.direction)), int(p.y - moveSpeed*sin(p.direction))) != color(renderDistance)) {
      p.x -= moveSpeed*cos(p.direction);
      p.y -= moveSpeed*sin(p.direction);
    }
  }
  if (d) {
    if (maze.get(int(p.x - moveSpeed*cos(p.direction-PI/2)), int(p.y - moveSpeed*sin(p.direction-PI/2))) != color(renderDistance)) {
      p.x -= moveSpeed*cos(p.direction-PI/2);
      p.y -= moveSpeed*sin(p.direction-PI/2);
    }
  }
  if (a) {
    if (maze.get(int(p.x - moveSpeed*cos(p.direction+PI/2)), int(p.y - moveSpeed*sin(p.direction+PI/2))) != color(renderDistance)) {
      p.x -= moveSpeed*cos(p.direction+PI/2);
      p.y -= moveSpeed*sin(p.direction+PI/2);
    }
  }
  
  popMatrix();
  
  p.direction += ((float)mouseX-(float)pmouseX)/100;
  
  if (!map) {
    pushStyle();

    noStroke();
    fill(0, 0, renderDistance);
    rect(0, 0, width, height/2);
    fill(0, 0, renderDistance*0.6);
    rect(0, height/2, width, height);

    popStyle();

    p.display();
  }   
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (key == 'w') {
    w = true;
  }
  if (key == 's') {
    s = true;
  }
  if (key == 'a') {
    a = true;
  }
  if (key == 'd') {
    d = true;
  }
  if (key == 'm') {
    map = true;
  }
}
void keyReleased() {
  if (key == 'w') {
    w = false;
  }
  if (key == 's') {
    s = false;
  }
  if (key == 'a') {
    a = false;
  }
  if (key == 'd') {
    d = false;
  }
  if (key == 'm') {
    map = false;
  }
}

class Player {
  float x, y, direction;
  
  Player(int x, int y, float direction) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;    
    this.direction = direction;
  }
  
  void display() {
    maze.loadPixels();
    
    for (float i = direction - fov; i < direction + fov; i += viewStep) {
      FloatList line = new FloatList();
      line = rayCast(i);
                                   
      float length_ = (height - maxLine - minLine - map(line.get(2), 0, renderDistance, minLine, maxLine));
      
      stroke(renderDistance - line.get(2), 0, 0);
      
      if (line.get(3) == 1){
        stroke(renderDistance - line.get(2));
      }
      
      if (renderDistance - line.get(2) > 1) {
        line(map(i, direction - fov/2, direction + fov, 0, width), height/2 + length_/2, map(i, direction - fov/2, direction + fov, 0, width), height/2 - length_/2); 
      }
    }
  }
  
  FloatList rayCast(float direction) {
    
    FloatList out = new FloatList();
    float rayx = x;
    float rayy = y;
    int steps = 0;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < renderDistance; i++) {
      if (maze.get(int(rayx), int(rayy)) != color(0)) {
        break;
      }
      
      rayx += stepSize * cos(direction);
      rayy += stepSize * sin(direction);

      steps++;
    }

    out.append(rayx);
    out.append(rayy);
    out.append(steps);
    if (rayx < 0 || rayx > width || rayy > height || rayy < 0) {
      out.append(1);
    } else {
      out.append(0);
    }
    return out;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your raycasting algorithm calculates the distance from the wall to an infinitely small focus point in the camera. When we try to project this onto our screen we get a distorted image because our screen is a plane and not a point or sphere.
To fix the distortion we have to calculate the distance from the wall to our screen instead of the focus point. This can be done with simple trigonometry:

multiply the raw (euclidean) distance by cos(angle) and you get the distance to the screen.

[drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CH46N.png)

So after cleaning up the code and adding the correction it looks like this:

```java
   void display() {
        maze.loadPixels();
        
        float wallHalfHeight = 50;
        float distanceFocusProjection = (height / 2) / tan(fov);

        for (float angle = -fov; angle < fov; angle += viewStep) {
            float euclideanDist = rayCast(direction + angle);

            if (euclideanDist < renderDistance) {
                float distToScreen = euclideanDist * cos(angle);
                float scanLineHalfHeight = wallHalfHeight * (distanceFocusProjection / distToScreen);
                float scanLineX = map(angle, -fov, fov, 0, width);
                
                stroke(renderDistance - distToScreen, 0, 0);
                line(scanLineX, height/2 + scanLineHalfHeight, scanLineX, height/2 - scanLineHalfHeight);
            }
        }
    }

    float rayCast(float angle) {
        PVector position = new PVector(x, y);
        PVector direction = PVector.fromAngle(angle); //new PVector(cos(angle), sin(angle));

        int distance;
        for(distance = 0; distance < renderDistance; distance++) {
            if (maze.get(round(position.x), round(position.y)) != color(0)) {
                break;
            }
            position.add(direction);
        }
        return distance;
    }
```